# Mod with a negative number

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I know how $\div$ and $\mathrm{mod}$ works but I have come across the following example and I do not understand it:

$-117 \pmod {352} = 235$

Shouldn't that be equal to $-117$?

Comment: But $-117 = 235 + \color{red}{(-1)}\cdot 352$, so $-117$ is, by definition, congruent to $235$ modulo $352$ (since there exists an integer that fits in the red spot).

Comment: You are thinking of "mod" as a binary operation, as is typical in a programming or computer science context.  The mathematical perspective involves congruence classes, so that the "answers" $-117$ and $235$ correspond to the same congruence class modulo $352$.  The programming versions will often provide options to accommodate various desires for "signed" inputs and outputs, so even then there is no single "correct" answer as you might have expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $0 \equiv 352 \pmod{352}$ it follows that
$$
-117 = 0 - 117 \equiv 352 - 117 = 235 \pmod{352}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $-117 = (-1)352 + 235 \in 235 + 352\mathbb{Z}$, which shows that $-117\equiv235 \mod 352$.